# Shell : Get a specific word under a sub section in yaml file

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed, grep

How do I get the value of `name`tag under `metadata` section of below yaml file.

```
    apiVersion: v1
    kind: Pod
    metadata:
      name: sss-pod-four
      namespace: default
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: sss-test-container
        image: anaudiyal/infinite-loop
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: "/mnt/sss"
          name: sss-test-volume
      volumes:
        - name: sss-test-volume
```

I need to get `sss-pod-four` string.

```
grep  "\sname: " config/pod.yaml | awk -F ": " '{print $2}'
```

The above code is printing 
`sss-pod-four` ,
`sss-test-container` and 
`sss-test-volume`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Could you please try following and let me know if this helps you.

```
awk '/metadata/{flag=1} flag && /name:/{print $NF;flag=""}'  Input_file
```

Adding a non one liner form of solution with explanation too now:

```
awk '
/metadata/{         ##checking a string metadata in current line here and if it is TRUE then do following:
 flag=1}            ##Making a variable named flag value TRUE here.
flag && /name:/{    ##Checking if variable named flag is TRUE here and current line has string name: in it then do following:
  print $NF;        ##Printing the last column of the current line here.
  flag=""           ##Making variable named flag value as NULL here.
}
' Input_file        ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: Nice answer, if there is only one occurrence of this pattern to fetch, than you can add an `exit` statement after `print $NF`;

Comment: Do note that on OSX this does not work when multiple lines with `name: ` exist.

Answer (score 6):

You can also use this `sed` command to reach your goal:

```
$ sed -n '/metadata:/,/spec:/p' input.yml | grep -oP '(?<=name: ).*'
sss-pod-four
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use GNU grep:

`grep -zoP '\n(\s*)metadata:(\n\1\s+.*)+name: \K.*' input.yml`

The `-z` flag splits lines on zero bytes, so that the entire file contents can be matched in a single regex. `-o` will let grep only output the match and `-P` enables Perl style regex, which is necessary for newline matching and for the `\K`, which restricts output to the no-newline characters following the left regex part.

What I do differently than the other solutions and what you could adapt to sed or awk is that I first measure the indentation of the `metadata:` line and then only continue the match while the indentation of the following lines is higher, so that it works correctly even if `spec:` doesn't follow `metadata:` and even if `metadata:` doesn't contain a `name` attribute.